# Strange behaviours receiving notifications from firebase on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have a project with two iOS apps configured on iOS. First I created one app on firebase console, downloaded the configuration file **(Google-services.plist)**, subscribed to a topic, and tried sending notifications from firebase console with success. Then, in the same `XCode` project, I changed the bundle identifier and the `google-services.plist` info with the info from another app. I deleted the app from the phone, made a clean and a build on the `XCode` project and tried to send notifications. I have no success, so I started making experiments.

After a while, I realized that I can send notifications to the device and to the topic so I tried sending notifications from the old app and then I realized that, strangely, I can receive notifications from the old app instead of the configurated app. It has no sense since the new app has a different bundle and a different `google-services.plist` pointing to the new bundle. Which could be my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found how to solve this. It seemed like Firebase notification server was the cause, so I deleted the two projects, created again and upload the .p12s again. Now all is working properly. I wrote these lines to help people with the same problem since I didn´t found anything similar on internet.